# How to focus camera shot?

Tags: android, focus, android-camera

I am able to run a code to take pictures but the resulting image is undesirable. In the following image, the Google logo should be at the center, but it isn't.

[image]

I'm using the following code:

**CameraView.java**

```
package com.pictures;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class CamaraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        OnClickListener {
    static final int FOTO_MODE = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraTest";
    Camera mCamera;
    boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
    private Context mContext = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            if (imageData != null) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent();

                StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,
                        "ImageName");
                mCamera.startPreview();

                setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                finish();

            }
        }
    };

    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = false;
        mCamera.release();
    }

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);

    }

    public static boolean StoreByteImage(Context mContext, byte[] imageData,
            int quality, String expName) {

        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Engagia");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        String nameFile;
        try {


            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;

            Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    imageData.length,options);


            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/image.jpg");


            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    fileOutputStream);

            myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.pictures"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".CamaraView"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">      
    </SurfaceView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone knows the solution for this? Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, that phone won't center the image inside viewfinder. User should do it by moving the phone.

To achieve autofocus, take a look at [autoFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus%28android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback%29) API.

Comment: I end up invoking the default camera of the android device :)

Comment: Seems it's the best choice if You don't need some specific camera overlay of functionality. On some devices Camera stuff is tricky (i.e. Motorola, some Samsungs) and many issues could be discovered is some corner cases - like fast opening/closing, launching camera via external key during Yours viewfinder active etc.